# mySQL request after onclick in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have read other Q&As regarding this topic and wasn't able to find similar to my needs. Please, provide me with your kind advice.

I have php page with the button at it. 
I have coded action at the press of it by creation special function update_base ()

```
onclick="update_base()"
```

Now I need to make mySQL request. But how to do it?
What should I write in this function.

If I use usually mysql request it doesn't work.

Could you show me right direction, please.

Comment: You need to use AJAX, that way you can call a javascript function on the button click which will, in turn, call your php page which will process your sql query

Comment: PHP cannot be executed on the client side, you need Javascript to do that. This is basics...

Comment: So, I need other php page? And have to put connection to database code at it? And Ajax will send parameters to php page, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Ajax

if you want to execute code serverside and not reload the page you need Asynchronized server calls (AJAX)

http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

## without AJAX

if you don't want to use ajax call

1. you can: wrap button inside a form (so you reload page on click)
2. in php execute update_base() php function

```html
<form name="input" action="" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Reload page">
</form>
```

Comment: if Ajax will be working for any browser or some will have turn off this setting?

Comment: Ajax is a functionality inside javascript (advised to use jQuery). Ajax works in every browser, unless javascript is disabled. !Take the time to read the url in my answer.

Comment: Joel, thank you very much. I'm ready it carefully. Good luck to you!

Comment: If you don't know what javascript and jQuery is, you are advised to  read a tutorial for these as well (first javascript, then jQuery) (jQuery is a framework on javascript). This will improve your live as a webdeveloper, and is a must when developing front end part of websites.